# Convert ArrayList of objects to Object Array for jasperreports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Ok. A big newbee question here but I've been trying in vain to find a solution.

Using the examples I found [here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#customdatasource) i was able to get a customdatasource working in my report.

But ... the example uses this bit of code for the actual object pased as data

```
private Object[][] data =
  {
   {"Berne", new Integer(22), "Bill Ott", "250 - 20th Ave."},
   {"Berne", new Integer(9), "James Schneider", "277 Seventh Av."},
   {"Boston", new Integer(32), "Michael Ott", "339 College Av."},
   {"Boston", new Integer(23), "Julia Heiniger", "358 College Av."}, etc...
```

Unfortunately java won't allow dynamically adding to that Object array and as the report data is always going to be dynamic, it becomes useless.

I've experimented with a custom data class with two elements that I add to an ArrayList like

```
ArrayList<myDataObject> a = new ArrayList<myDataObject>();

for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
    myDataObject myl = new myDataObject("asdasd",Integer.toString(x));
    a.add(myl);
}
```

But (here's the newbee part) i can't seem to figure out how to convert this to a simple Object[][] that jasper expects.

Here's the data class I'm using

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField;

public class CustomData implements JRDataSource {

    private Object data[][];
    private int index;


//    public CustomData(Object o[][]) {
//        index = -1;
//        this.data = o;
//    }
     public CustomData(ArrayList <Object> a) {
        index = -1;
        this.data = (Object)a.toArray();
    }

    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        index++;
        return (index < data.length);
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        Object value = null;
        String fieldName = field.getName();

        if ("aName".equals(fieldName)) {
            value = data[index][0];
        }
        else if ("aNumber".equals(fieldName)) {
            value = data[index][1];
        }

        return (String)value;
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterating through the list and adding it to the 2-dimensional array would come to mind:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<MyDataObject> a = new ArrayList<MyDataObject>();

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        MyDataObject myl = new MyDataObject("asdasd", Integer.toString(x));
        a.add(myl);
    }

    int aSize = a.size();
    Object[][] thingy = new Object[aSize][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < aSize; i++) {
        MyDataObject mdo = a.get(i);
        thingy[i][0] = mdo.getS();
        thingy[i][1] = mdo.getI();
    }
}
```

Comment: YES. That worked! I wasn't able to 'add' to the Object[][] so I got stuck, but... an 'Object[][]' must be allocated space beforehand, like an Array. Got it. Makes sense. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to hit accept if you think my answer has helped you on your way. Actually Object[][] is just an array of arrays (immitating a 2 dimensional array) of object references.